# Sheetで表示させた際に、キーボードのToolBarが表示されない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swiftui

`ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard)`を使用した際に、`NavigationLink`での遷移ではキーボード上に表示されるのですが、`Sheet`で遷移すると表示されません。

Sheetのような形で遷移して`ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard)`を表示する方法はあるでしょうか？

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var isPresented = false

  var body: some View {
    Button {
      isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Button")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
      SubView()
    }
  }
}

struct SubView: View {
  @State var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      TextEditor(text: $text)
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("Click") {
            }
          }
          ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Button("Click") {
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 16 beta 5で直ったようです。

一応Forumのリンクを載せておきます。

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709227